# Java: How to download chunked content correctly?

Tags: java, chunked-encoding, chunked, http-chunked

I have to download file which HTTP response is "Transfer-Encoding: Chunked", because of what I can't to «getContentLength» to allocate new bytes buffer for DataInputStream.
Can you advice me how to do it correctly?

Code example is very simple:

`try
{
       dCon = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(torrentFileDownloadLink.absUrl("href")).openConnection();
       dCon.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "session=" + cookies.get("session"));
       dCon.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
       dCon.setRequestMethod("GET");
       dCon.setConnectTimeout(120000);
       dCon.setReadTimeout(120000);`

```
      // byte[] downloadedFile == ???

      DataInputStream br = new DataInputStream((dCon.getInputStream()));
      br.readFully(downloadedFile);
      System.out.println(downloadedFile);
```

}
catch(IOException ex)
{
       Logger.getLogger(WhatCDWork.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}

Answer (score 1):

The `HttpURLConnection` will take care of all the de-chunking for you. Just copy the bytes until end of stream:

```
byte[] buffer = new  byte[8192];
int count;
while ((count = in.read( buffer)) > 0)
{
    out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
out.close();
in.close();
```

where `out` is whatever `OutputStream` you want to save the data to. Could even be a `ByteArrayOutputStream` if you really need it in memory, although this isn't advisable as not everything fits into memory.

NB `GET` is already the default request method. You don't have to set it.