# How to Extract Chunked data when using HttpURLConnection in android

Tags: java, android, rest, chunked-encoding

I am using HttpURLConnection to get data when i am making a REST API call.

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL("http://" + account + ".table.core.windows.net/"+urlPath)).openConnection();
connection..connect();
```

The response that i am getting is chunked data that i found using WireShark.
I want that data to be displayed in my application. How to get this chunked data using  HttpURLConnection. ?? 
Below is response in wireshark

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: How to download chunked content correctly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5737945/java-how-to-download-chunked-content-correctly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi the below code works in this situation.

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL("http://" + account + ".table.core.windows.net/"+urlPath)).openConnection();

    signRequestSK(connection, account, key);

    connection.connect();

    ByteArrayOutputStream sink = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    copy(connection.getInputStream(), sink, 3000);  
    byte[] downloadedFile = sink.toByteArray();
    String str = new String(downloadedFile, "UTF8");


    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alert.setTitle("Title");
    alert.setMessage(str);
    alert.show();
```

Copy Function

```
      public static void copy(InputStream in, OutputStream out , int bufferSize)
           throws IOException
        {
           // Read bytes and write to destination until eof
           byte[] buf = new byte[bufferSize];
           int len = 0;
           while ((len = in.read(buf)) >= 0)
           {
              out.write(buf, 0, len);
           }
        }
```